# How to seamlessly multi target Electron debug with VSCode using the legacy protocol, electron 1.6.7 , node v6.11.1, vscode 1.17 and firefox?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, node.js, visual-studio-code

I recently read the article ,Multi target Electron debugging with VSCode whose URL is https://kwonoj.github.io/en/post/multi-target-dbg-electron-vscode/ and got it to work seamlessly in an Oracle VM VirtuaBox Manager  containing the RedHat Linux 7.1 operating system with electron 1.8.2 , node v8.9.4 , vscode 1.17 and firefox using the inspector protocol. Here is my launch.json which set breakpoints inside main.js and main.cpp , a C++ addon which calculates if an integer is a prime number.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type":"cppdbg",
            "program": "/home/hellodev/Downloads/node-v6.11.1-linux-x64/bin/node"
            "args": [
                "--inspect-brk=5858",
                "main.js"
            ],
            "request": "launch",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "serverLaunchTimeout": 50000
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "timeout":  10000,
            "name": "Attach Program",
            "port": 5858,
            "protocol": "inspector"
        },
        {
            "type":"node",
            "request":"launch",
            "name":"Electron Main",
            "runtimeExecutable":"/home/hellodev/node-cpp-addons/node_modules/electron/dist/electron"
            "protocol":"inspector"
         }

    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Electron Main","(gdb) Launch","Attach Program"]
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I also extend this article in the same Oracle VM VirtuaBox Manager  containing the RedHat Linux 7.1 operating system to use the legacy protocol, electron 1.6.7 , node v6.11.1, vscode 1.17 and firefox and what would the revised launch.json look like?

With no success, I tried an electron prelaunch task whose tasks.json is shown below, The reason I tried an prelaunch task is because runtimeExecutable is reserved for the inspector protocol rather than the legacy protocol. However, the prelaunch task causes a runtime error EADDRESSINUSE:port 5858.

```
{
    "version": "1.6.7",
    "command": "electron",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [

"--remote-debugging-port=5858",   
       "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
    ]
}
```

and got the error message , "Cannot connect to runtime process: Reason: Socket ended by other party" when I  used the following launch.json with the vscode green arrow to run an compound launch configuration.

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type":"cppdbg",
            "program": "/home/hellodev/Downloads/node-v6.11.1-linux-x64/bin/node"
            "args": [
               "--inspect-brk=5858",
                "main.js"
            ],
            "request": "launch",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "serverLaunchTimeout": 50000
},
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "timeout":  10000,
            "name": "Attach Program",
            "port": 5858,
            "protocol": "legacy"
         },
        {
            "type":"node",
            "request":"launch",
            "name":"Electron Main",
            "preLaunchTask": "electron",
            "protocol":"legacy", //Specify to use v8 inspector protocol
            "port": 5858,
            "timeout": 28000
         }


    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Electron Main","(gdb) Launch","Attach Program"]
        }
    ]

}
```

[Fenruary 24 2018] @Andre Weinand, I show here my newest launch.json which causes the error message "Cannot connect to runtime; make sure that runtime is in 'legacy' debug mode." to  display. I have tried to follow all of your earlier recommendations but I still am encountering problems. Therefore , when I click the vscode green arrow corresponding to the Server/Client compound launch configuration , it launches "Electron Main" but does not hit the GDB breakpoints I set in main.cpp which is a C++ addon.  I understand what you are saying about placing debugger statements in the C++ addon source code but I would prefer not to do. How could I fix my launch.json?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type":"cppdbg",
            "program": "/home/xyzdev/Downloads/node-v6.11.1-linux-x64/bin/node"
            "args": [
                "--debug=5858"
                "main.js"
            ],
            "request": "launch",
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
             "launchCompleteCommand": "None"

        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "timeout":  10000,
            "name": "Attach Program",
            "port": 5858,
            "protocol": "legacy"
        },
        {
            "type":"node",
            "request":"launch",
            "name":"Electron Main",
            "runtimeExecutable":"/home/xyzdev/node-cpp-addons/node_modules/electron/dist/electron",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
                "--remote-debugging-port" //Set debugging port for renderer process
            ],
            "protocol":"legacy"
         }


    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Electron Main","(gdb) Launch","Attach Program"]
        }
    ]

}
```

[February 26 2018] @Andre Weinand, I read that you wrote on May 10 2017 in the github.com article https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26411 that states:  "You can use either "legacy" or "inspector" protocol for node version > 6.3 and < 8.0, but you have to make sure that you are using the matching "--debug" or "--inspect" argument.

BTW, this redundancy in the launch config will be fixed in the May release: you'll no longer have to specify a port at all, just the protocol will do the right thing."                                                                            Since I am using node version 6.11.1 which is > 6.3 and < 8.0 , I was wondering whether I could switch our launch.json to the "inspector" protocol instead of the "legacy" protocol to attain "seamless" debugging as I was able to do with node 8.9.4? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "protocol" attribute determines whether the "inspector" or "legacy" protocol is used. Please read our doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_supported-nodelike-runtimes.

You cannot run two debug sessions with the same debug port in parallel (which you do in the last debug configuration from above). And there is a "program" or "runtimeExecutable" missing.

I suggest to change the value of the "protocol" attribute in the top most debug configuration to "legacy" (assuming that the protocol is the only problem of that configuration).

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer. I am wondering whether I need to assign the legacy protocol value to the top most (gdb) Launch debug configuration. Also, I was able to use the same debug port(i.e 5858) in parallel when running with the inspector protocol rather than the legacy protocol. May I ask what ports I should choose to avoid the EADDRESSINUSE error?Thank you.

Comment: In my haste to ask the original question, I may have omitted the fact that I used a compound launch configuration where Electron Main and (gdb) Launch and Attach Program take place sequentially rather than in parallel. Thank you for catching my mistake with the preLaunch task which occurs in parallel,

Comment: I just accepted your nice answer. Does one have to explicltly enable the Firefox browser to be  devtools.chrome.enabled using about:config so vscode can capitalize on the v8 Chrome debugging legacy protocol ? Thank you,

Comment: Your "cppdbg" configuration does not involve node.js debugging. So, using the "protocol" attribute does not make any sense (and is not supported as you can find out by using it: you will see an error squiggly). 
However, the "cppdbg" configuration launches node.js and since you are passing a "--inspect-brk=5858" you've configured it for debugging in "inspector "mode. If you want to use another debug session with this node, you have to use matching protocols. So for "legacy" protocol do not start the first node with a "--inspect..." but use a "--debug" argument.

Comment: You can use any free debug port. For your first "cppdbg" configuration I suggest that you specify a port explicitly (what you already do) because it has to match a port in another launch config ("Attach Program" I assume).
In your last "Electron Main"  launch config I suggest not to specify a port. In this case VS Code picks a free port automatically.

Comment: Before trying a composite launch config make sure that the individual launch configs work by starting them one after another manually.

Comment: I cannot say anything about FireFox because I don't use it.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I found out this morning that you are almost 99% correct. Are you cognizant that upon attaching with vscode , Electron 1.6.8 ignores breakpoints? What should I do about that? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I apologize that I misspelled runtimeExecutable.What should I do to fix the following error:      Error: The module './build/Debug/addon.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 53. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module 
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20) Thank you.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I forgot to mention that  I just ran node-gyp rebuild --debug in an attempt to fix the error: Error: The module './build/Debug/addon.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. Thanks.

Comment: @Andre  Weinand, I noticed that my package.json contains an entry for electron ^1,6.8 and electron-rebuild ^1,7.3. Could that be the cause of the error ,  Error: The module './build/Debug/addon.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 53 , I observed yesterday? Thank you.

Comment: If Electron 1.6.8 appears to ignore breakpoints, then typically you are trying to debug the wrong process. Try to use a "debugger" statement instead of a breakpoint. If you still do not hit it, my hypothesis is correct.

Comment: When using native node modules with electron, you will have to build them against the node that is contained in the Electron version, and not against an external node version that happens to have the same version.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I have added a new section  at the bottom of my original SuperUser Stack Exchange question. May I ask if you could look at it and tell me what I need to change in  launch.json so my compound launch configuration "Server/Client" could seamlessly hit all the main.js and main.cpp breakpoints I set seamlessly with the legacy protocol? Thank you.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, How do I rebuild my C++ addon addon.node so that I can fix the the error , "Error: The module './build/Debug/addon.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 53." My package.json contains an entry for electron ^1,6.8 and electron-rebuild ^1,7.3. My node version is node 6.11.1. Thank you.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I read that you wrote on May 10 2017 in the github.com article https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26411 that states:  "You can use either "legacy" or "inspector" protocol for node version > 6.3 and < 8.0, but you have to make sure that you are using the matching "--debug" or "--inspect" argument. Since I am using node version 6.11.1 which is > 6.3 and < 8.0 , I was wondering whether I could switch our launch.json to the "inspector" protocol instead of the "legacy" protocol to attain "seamless" debugging as I was able to do with node 8.9.4? Thank you

Comment: Electron has a builtin node.js that either supports legacy or inspector but not both. Electron switched from legacy to inspector in version 1.7.4 (I think). So you should know what you can use in your case.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I am using Electron 1.6.8 and Node 6.11.1 in my launch.json. When I switch to inspector protocol from legacy protocol, I use the runtimeArg of [ --inspect=5858] but the debug console shows --inspect=19763 and Error Connection refused at port 19763. How could I fix this error which I observed yesterday? Thank you.

Comment: Did you read and understand my previous post?
If you are using Electron 1.6.8 (which is older than 1.7.4), only the "legacy" protocol is supported. So it doesn't make sense to try to use the "inspector" protocol.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, JavaScript has a debugger statement while C++ does not have a debugger statement. Therefore, should I conclude that we have to wait until electron 1.8.2  and node 8.9.4 are released to our git open source software repository which sits behind a HTTP corporate proxy to offer users a seamless debugging experience using the  inspector protocol? Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is the relation between the debugger statement and electron and node versions?

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I recall you stated on February 21 that "If Electron 1.6.8 appears to ignore breakpoints, then typically you are trying to debug the wrong process. Try to use a "debugger" statement instead of a breakpoint." But after extensive google searching , I discovered that there are no c++  "debugger" statements that emulate strategically placed gdb breakpoints. As a result, I concluded there is no remedy to Electron 1.6.8 appearing to  ignore breakpoints when used with the "legacy" protocol. Could I nvm install Electron 1.7.4 in concert with node 6.11.1 and run them both as inspector?

Comment: I was assuming that you want to debug the JavaScript parts of an Electron application because almost nobody would ever debug the C++ parts of Electron. For that reason I mentioned to use the "debugger" statement. If you need to debug C++ I cannot help you (and there is no debugger statement). The "legacy" vs "inspector" protocol issue applies to node.js only. It has nothing to do with C++. If you have issues with C++ breakpoints I cannot help you (because I only wrote the VS Code node debugger).

Comment: When using Electron you are not free to choose a node.js version as Electron only uses the node,js that is built into it. So by picking a specific Electron version you select a node.js version as well. That determines whether the node debugging has to use the "legacy" or the "inspector" protocol. But this is completely independent from C++ debugging. The C++ debugger of VS Code is a separate extension that is only required if you develop native node-modules (for example).

Comment: @Andre Weinand  , We not want to debug the C++ parts or internals of Electron. Rather, we wish to debug an C++ add-on module which calculates if an integer is a prime number. Is there  any recourse for us to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: How is this add-on module integrated into Electron? Via a node module?

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I believe that our C++ add-on module is integrated with Electron via a node module. The entire details of our open-source proof on concept are described in this  article:https://medium.com/@marcinbaraniecki/extending-node-js-with-native-c-modules-63294a91ce4. Could I ask you to survey it? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I suggest that you just focus on the C++ debugging of your native code. There is no need to debug any JavaScript in your case, so the "legacy" vs. "inspector" protocol discussion is moot.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I followed your suggestion to just focus on the C++ debugging of our native code using gdb with vscode and it worked. However, now I would like to do node application(i.e. main.js) breakpointing in vscode before and/or after the gdb thread debugging. If that is possible, how might we do that with electron 1.6.8 and node 6.11.1? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @Andre Weinand, I received the error message "Cannot connect to runtime process. Socket ended by other party"  when I switched from electron 1.6.8 to electron 1.6.7. Then when I used fuser 5858/tcp, it revealed that a vscode process was listening on port 5858, an electon 1,6.7 process was listening on port 5858, and that a tcp connection had been established from the  vscode process to electron 1.6.7 when I ran the "Electron Main" piece of my compond launch configuration. Is there a way to fix this error so I can seamlessly switch from "Electron Main" to gdb launch? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot have two or more processes listening on the same port! So do not use the default "--debug" flag in this case because it will start to listen on port 5858. Instead use something like "--debug=6666". But make sure that you use the same port in your launch config, so specify `"port": 6666`. In addition start only trying the compound launches if the individual pieces work.